# Simple bing "trending searches" scraper with apify

Tags: jquery, bing, apify

I'm very new to scraping/apify but am trying to do something that should be simple, get the "trending searches" on bing.com when the search textbox is in focus.

Currently, I have:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
  
function myTrim(x) {
  return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}
  
    const $ = context.jQuery;

    // log an alert when the search box gets focus
    $( "#sb_form_q").focus(function() {
      context.log.info('focus on the input box');
    });

    $("#sb_form_q").focus();

    // wait for the resulting div to appear 
    context.waitFor('#sw_as');
    context.log.info('div #sw_as appeared');
    
    const myTerm = $("li div.sa_tm").find("span.sa_tm_text").text();

    // Return an object with the data extracted from the page.
    // It will be stored to the resulting dataset.
    return {
        myTerm
    };
}
```

As I said, I am relatively new to apify/actors so I would appreciate any assistance. I am thinking it should be simple, but it just isn't clicking. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be after are suggestions for previously typed in queries that appear after clicking the search field and while your code itself works fine, the suggestions will only be available for certain browsing session persisted in cookies, theoretically even depend on specific IP but that doesn't seem to be the case so all you should need to do to restore a previous user session is to load cookies into the page before anything else. Have a look here about how to do that: http://docs.apify.com/tutorials/log-in-by-transferring-cookies

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure that is  quite right. Bing gives "trending" search results (suggestions) even when the focus is set without typing anything. It might be IP dependent as far as country, which is fine, but the suggestions in a LI list appear even when nothing is entered, just on focus. They are not tied to previous searches

Comment: @Trutter Indeed, behavior is different via proxy. The elements you are querying do seem to exist. In this case I would recommend debugging visually with https://docs.apify.com/tutorials/analyze-pages-and-fix-errors#saving-snapshots